# Set Validation for 2 Datepicker Start Date and End Date javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, date, datepicker

Ok i have this issue. I have two datepickers one is Start Date and the other End Date.

i want a perform a javascript validation whereby the end date cannot be less than the start date so.e.g if user clicks Start Date and select 2nd April 2015 then when user clicks End date, it automatically should make the dates shown on the calendar to not be lesser than the start date.

I I am attaching my plunkr code. http://plnkr.co/edit/nsf6o2hlYrt3pFfJCFn2

javascript.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#activity-customer-start-period').datepicker({
    format: 'dd M yyyy', 
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        console.log(selected)
      $("#activity-customer-end-period").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
    }
  });

  $('#activity-customer-end-period').datepicker({
    format: 'dd M yyyy', 
    autoclose: true,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        console.log(selected)
      $("#activity-customer-start-period").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
    }
  });

})
```

index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h5>Start Time </h5>
    <input id="activity-customer-start-period" name="start_period" placeholder="" type="text">
    <br/>
    <h5>End Time</h5>
    <input  id="activity-customer-end-period" name="end_period" placeholder="" type="text">
  </body>

</html>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: added a fiddle file maybe u can help me solve it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

**HTML Part:**

```
<div class="start_date"></div>
<div class="end_date"></div>
```

**JS Part:**

```
 var dates = jQuery('.start_date, .end_date').datepicker("option", "onSelect", 
   function(selectedDate){
       var $this = $(this),
           option = $this.hasClass("start_date") ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
           adjust = $this.hasClass("start_date") ? 1 : -1,
           base_date = new Date(selectedDate),
           new_date = new Date();

       new_date.setDate(base_date.getDate() + (1 * adjust));
       dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, new_date);

   }
);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/antoKing/no86nea5/1/) Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below option in your end-date field.

```
minDate: $('#activity-customer-start-period').val(),
```

Do this:

```
*$('#activity-customer-end-period').datepicker({
    format: 'dd M yyyy', 
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: $('#activity-customer-start-period').val(),
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        console.log(selected)
      $("#activity-customer-start-period").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
    }
  });
```

This will work for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/boyfunky/oqxxmrru/ i have a fiddle file maybe you can help me solve it from here?

Comment: You have not added library in the fiddle. and the field name was not correct. You can see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/f7j6kn3b/